# trying to set page margins in excel through xml

Tags: xml, excel, formatting, xml-namespaces

i have 'inherited' some code that downloads data to an excel spreadsheet.  The same tables formatting the html are generating the excel data.

i am trying to set the page-margins for the worksheet.  the following code doesn't really do it. i think the xml data is ignored.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
<style>
  @page 
    {
        mso-page-orientation:portrait;
    }
</style>

    <xml> 
         <x:ExcelWorkbook> 
          <x:ExcelWorksheets> 
           <x:ExcelWorksheet> 
                <x:Name>HoursReport</x:Name> 
                <x:WorksheetOptions>
                <x:Selected/>
                <x:FreezePanes/>
                <x:FrozenNoSplit/>
                <!--- Bottom row number of top pane. --->
                <x:SplitHorizontal>4</x:SplitHorizontal>
                <x:TopRowBottomPane>4</x:TopRowBottomPane>

                  <x:PageSetup>
                    <x:Header x:Margin="0.25"/>
                    <x:Footer x:Margin="0.25"/>
                    <x:PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
                   </x:PageSetup>

                 <x:FitToPage/> 
                 <x:Print> 
                  <x:FitHeight>99</x:FitHeight>
                  <x:ValidPrinterInfo/> 
                  <x:Scale>100</x:Scale> 
                  <HorizontalResolution>600</HorizontalResolution> 
                  <VerticalResolution>600</VerticalResolution> 
                 </x:Print> 
                 <x:Selected/> 
                    <x:ActivePane>2</x:ActivePane>
                 <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents> 
                 <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects> 
                 <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>
                </x:WorksheetOptions> 
           </x:ExcelWorksheet> 
          </x:ExcelWorksheets> 
          <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure> 
          <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows> 
         </x:ExcelWorkbook> 
         <x:ExcelName> 
          <x:Name>Print_Titles</x:Name> 
          <x:SheetIndex>1</x:SheetIndex>
          <x:Formula>='HoursReport'!$1:$4</x:Formula>
         </x:ExcelName> 
</xml>
</head>
```

i am new to everything here - asp.net, c#, xml, excel...:)  i've gotten the other excel commands to work - splitting and freezing panes etc.  but the page-margins don't seem to do anything.

anyone out there that can straighten me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

was trying to accomplish the same thing and the PageMargins tag doesn't seem to work, what did work was using CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--

@page {
margin:.0in .0in .0in .0in;
mso-header-margin:.0in;
mso-footer-margin:.0in;
mso-page-orientation:portrait;
}

@print {
margin:.0in .0in .0in .0in;
mso-header-margin:.0in;
mso-footer-margin:.0in;
mso-page-orientation:portrait;
}

-->
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ss:Worksheet>
  <x:WorksheetOptions>
    <x:PageSetup>
      <x:PageMargins x:Bottom="1.5" x:Left=".25" x:Right=".25" x:Top="1.5" />
    </x:PageSetup>
  </x:WorksheetOptions>
</ss:Worksheet>
```

Your page setup options go inside of the `WorksheetOptions` tag. I placed mine right after the beginning `Worksheet` tag. It works like a charm.

Comment: It does not work. At least with a xlsx file read by Excel 2018, it gets completely ignored.

Comment: As an additional information, there is no property `WorksheetOptions` in the specs. See here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.worksheet?view=openxml-2.8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.worksheet?view=openxml-2.8.1)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
<x:pageMargins x:left="0.7" x:right="0.7" x:top="0.75" x:bottom="0.75" x:header="0.3" x:footer="0.3" />
```

as a child element within the `<x:ExcelWorksheet>` element rather than in the `<x:PageSetup>` element

Comment: Hi Mark - thanks for the response.  I changed the location of the pageMargins to excelWorksheet.  Still no luck.  the file that gets downloaded has removed any reference to page margins,  when I physically add it and reopen in excel, I get errors.